# Calculation of Klein bottle Integral Simplicial Homology the $H_{1}$ case

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, abelian-groups

I am new to algebraic topology.

Martin Crossley in his Essential Topology shows how to calculate $$H_{1}(K)$$ if $K$ is the Klein bottle triangulation using simplicial complex, in example 9.17 on page 164.

It is shown that $$H_{1}(K)= \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2$$

But I cannot follow this result and how we calculate it.

I see that based on the definition we have $$H_{1}(K)= Ker \delta_{1}/ Img \delta_{2}$$

Could you fill in the gap for me here. How we get from this definition to the result above?

In particular, could you list a number of elements in $H_{1}(K)$ so that I get a sense of what are the elements in the quotient group?

Answer (score 4):

I can choose the simplicial complex of a square to be :

$C_0 = \mathbb Z \langle a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4 \rangle$

$C_1 = \mathbb Z \langle x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5\rangle$

$C_2 = \mathbb Z \langle \Delta_1,\Delta_2 \rangle$

according to this drawing :

[image]

If I glue $x_1$ to $x_4$ and $x_2$ to $x_5$ (hence also $a_1$ to $a_2$ to $a_3$ to $a_4$), this induces a simplicial complex

$C_0 = \mathbb Z \langle a_1 \rangle$

$C_1 = \mathbb Z \langle x_1, x_2, x_3\rangle$

$C_2 = \mathbb Z \langle \Delta_1,\Delta_2 \rangle$

for the Klein bottle $K$.

Now the boundaries are :

$\partial_0 a_1 = 0$

$\partial_1 x_1 = 0$

$\partial_1 x_2 = 0$

$\partial_1 x_3 = 0$

$\partial_2 \Delta_1 = x_1 + x_2 + x_3$

$\partial_2 \Delta_2 = - x_4 + x_5 - x_3 = -x_1 + x_2 - x_3$

We can now calculate explicitly $H_1(K)$ :
$$
H_1(K) = \frac{ker \partial_1}{im \partial_2}
\\ = \frac{\mathbb Z \langle x_1, x_2, x_3\rangle}{\mathbb Z \langle x_1 + x_2 + x_3, -x_1 + x_2 - x_3\rangle}
\\ = \mathbb Z \langle x_1, x_2, x_3| x_1 + x_2 + x_3, -x_1 + x_2 - x_3\rangle
\\ = \mathbb Z \langle x_1, x_2, -x_1 - x_2| 2x_2 = 0\rangle
\\ \cong \mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z_2
$$

Comment: Sorry this does not answer my question. Could you use algebra and the simplexes and use the definition for H1  above.

Comment: The loops are continuous images of triangles (i.e. simplices). They are without boundary, hence in $\ker \delta$. The loops I talked about (lets say $x$ and $y$) are representatives of non-trivial homology classes since they are not boundaries. What remains to show is that to any other loop we can glue some $x$ and $y$ to get a loop which is a boundary.

Comment: Could you list some of 1-simplexes chains in H1(K)?

Comment: As I just said, $x$ and $y$ are representatives (i.e. elements of the complex) of generators (lets say $x'$ and $y'$) of $H_1(K)$. So you have $H_1(K) = \mathbb Z \langle x', y' | 2y'=0 \rangle$. Any other element of $H_1(K)$ is a combination of $x'$ and $y'$. Here's a list : $x'$, $y'$, $-x'$, $x'+y'$, $451x'+y'$, $666 x'$, etc. Or I don't get your question.

Comment: It seems that I do not get sense of the notation $\oplus$ used.

Comment: $\oplus$ is a direct sum.

Comment: But is H1 a vector space or simply a group. If it is only a group a direct sum does not make sense! We should have a product group.

Comment: It's a module. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(mathematics)

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum_of_modules

Comment: Could you also list a few of the elements in Img $\delta_{2}$

Comment: The question is about simplicial homology. The answer is not.

Comment: Loops can be seen as images of triangles. Surfaces can be triangulated as solid triangles also (i.e. chains that are boundaries). Why is the answer not correct ?

Comment: @VVM some elements of the image of $\delta_2$ would be the boundaries of $\Delta_1$ and $\Delta_2$.